# How to write a quickfix list to a file

Tags: vim, ipdb

I'm looking for a way to write content of a quickfix window to a file with a specific formatting, preferably in a way that is easily scriptable.

What I'm trying to achieve is a very light integration of Vim and ipdb:

1. I set 'breakpoints' as items on a quickfix list with mapping:
   `nmap <leader>s :call setqflist([], 'a', {'items': [{'filename': @%, 'lnum':line('.'), 'text':'break'}]})`
2. Write content of the quickfix to `.pdbrc` file with `break file_path:line_number` formatting
3. Run ipdb on specified script

Comment: I just checked, you can definitely save quickfix contents using `:w`.

Comment: yeah, i know, but what if quickfix window is not currently open? and this misses my formatting requirement

Comment: Presumably, you're going to write a vim function that does all this automatically. So in that function, after you get the formatting done, you can do a quick set of calls (`:copen`, `:w save_file`, and `:q`) to open quickfix, save to file, and close it. That takes care of one problem. The other is the formatting which hopefully romainl's answer helps you solve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. Turning `items` into a list of properly formatted lines.

   You will need to:

   - get the quickfix list with `:help getqflist()`,
   - format each item of the list with `:help map()`,
   - derive `file_path` from the `bufnr` field with `:help bufname()` and possibly `:help fnamemodify()`.
2. Writing that list to a given file.

   You will need `:help writefile()`.